Wireguard and Ubuntu 22.04. Forcing traffic from port 25 over VPN
So Im hosting a server in a docker container which is a client in a VPN network. I Cant send any egress traffic out of port (say ummm 52) through the host. That box is a client to a wireguard server. If i set up the client config:
[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

Then i can egress port 52, no problem. If I change that to say:
[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24

Then the server doesnt know it should send traffic from ANY ip using port 52 for egress out of that VPN instead of the local machine. Im using Ubuntu 22.04 for this on the docker host. What is the best way to get around this? (Forward any traffic trying to egress over port 52 through the VPN)
To add to this, I'm decent with ubuntu/networking/firewalls but when it comes to iptables or any complex routing like this im a total newb.

what is the address that you want to access on port 53 ?

Its a docker container listening on 52.  So any traffic coming in will get picked up by it.  The problem is sending requests on that port.  They go through the host internet and not the VPN.  If that makes sense?

What is the business related issue in the current point of question? What is what you want to solve with this? mostly a description will likely more help to understand this

I need port 52 to egress to one interface and all other traffic can to to the default host interface.
